# Please explain 'if and how' and how paraphrase it

Tags: meaning, word-usage

Please explain 'if' and how paraphrase it.

> Now, researchers aim to learn **if and how** animals can really enjoy
>   their lives.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That form is collapsing two statements into one:

> They aim to learn if animals have fun.
>
> They aim to learn how animals have fun.

It is usually expressed as follows, so as not to make the *how*-clause a foregone conclusion:

> They aim to learn if, and if so, how animals have fun.

Comment: Interestingly, with the related usage [*When and if it happens / If and when it happens*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=When+and+if+it+happens%2CIf+and+when+it+happens&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CWhen%20and%20if%20it%20happens%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CIf%20and%20when%20it%20happens%3B%2Cc0) I see nothing particularly "unusual" about either sequence. But ***how and if*** doesn't seem to work at all.